# Equation for vibrating cantilever in SHM

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, oscillators

what is the equation connecting the period of oscillation of a ruler/cantilever with its length? my relation indicates that $T\propto L^2$ but i dont know if it is good

Comment: What does T->L^2 mean?

Comment: @gonenc, period is proportional to the squared length of the wave, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

You need to see the section

["Dynamic Beam Equation" on the "Euler-Bernoulli Beam Theory" Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler-Bernoulli_beam_theory#Dynamic_beam_equation)

The period depends on the length $L$ as well as the linear density $\mu$, Young's modulus $E$, area second moment $I$ of the beam's cross section as well as the modal mixture present. In general, the motion is **not** periodic, it is only so if there is only one mode present. You'll see that, for a given mode, the period is proportional to $L^2$. The form of the equation is $\omega_n=\beta_n\sqrt{\frac{E\,I}{\mu}}$ where $\beta_n$ is the solution of a transcendental eigenvalue equation for the modal frequency.

Answer (score 0):

If the Wikipedia section with beam equation is hard to answer, there is a simpler Wikipedia answer that may be easier if the end of your ruler is pivoting, not fixed at the end, that's easier to understand:

["Compound Pendulum" on the Pendulum Wikipedia Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum#Compound_pendulum)

In general as stated above, fixing a beam (even cantilever, as you mentioned) at one end, at both ends, in the middle, etc is a pretty tough equation.  But the pivoting ruler is a great place to start to understand the intuition and mechanics.